# relay state usage for SAML 2.0 and saml2-js npm module

Tags: node.js, saml-2.0, node-modules

I am using version:  saml2-js 2.0.1.

I am getting this error when the serviceProvider object's post_assert function call --

{ [Error: SAML Response is not valid for this audience]
  message: 'SAML Response is not valid for this audience',
  extra: undefined }

when I have the relay_state in the options object.

Similar to the example (https://github.com/Clever/saml2#example-express-implementation), my post_assert function callback guts looks like:

```
function(err, saml_response) {
    if (err != null) {
        console.log('error in post assert');
        console.log(err);
        return res.send(500);
    }
    res.send(`Hello ${saml_response.user.name_id}!`);
}
```

My saml_response object looks like -- which i constructed -- i suspect there might be something wrong here:

`{ SAMLResponse: 'some_valid_saml2_response',
  relay_state: 'some_valid_saml2_response' }`

Here is the identity provider options object I am sending.

```
// Create identity provider
var idp_options = {
    sso_login_url: https://myidp.com,
    sso_logout_url: "https://myidp.com/logout",
    certificates: ['abcd'],
    allow_unencrypted_assertion: true
};
```

in the sp.create function, i setting relay state in the options object (second arg).

```
 sp.create_login_request_url(idp, {relay_state: 'some-app-state'}, function(err, login_url, request_id) {
 if (err != null){
   ...
```

My question is:

Am I not using the relay state properly?  Please advise.

I should also point out -- when I do not have the relay state being sent, everything works just fine.  So definitely there is something with the relay state -- usage or the saml2-js module's handling..

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved.  The problem was exactly as the error described.  The payload was intended to be consumed a different entity -- not the SP.